# Mat-error not working properly with mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm making a form and I want to add an error throw if there is no value.

For the text inputs it's okay, but with the `<mat-select>` it's not working.

Here is the declaration of the mat-select in the .ts file :

```
    {
        id: 'role',
        label: marker('USER.role'),
        type: 'select',
        values: [],
        control: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        required: true
    }
```

And the HTML :

```
<mat-form-field class="block" *ngIf="field.type == 'select'">
    <mat-label>{{ field.label | translate }}</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(value)]="field.control.value" [required]="field.required">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of field.values" [value]="option['id']">{{ option['label'] }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="field.control.invalid">{{ getErrorMessage(field.id) }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

The `getErrorMessage` is like this :

```
getErrorMessage(field: any) {
    let error = undefined;
    this.userForm.forEach(element => {
        if(element.id == field)
            if (element.required){
                error = this.translate.instant('AUTH.field_required');
            }
    })
    return error
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you re create this problem inside stackblitz ?

Comment: All you need is this `<mat-select
      [formControl]="field.control"
    >` and then if you click submit button without selecting any value then mat-error is shown to you. here is demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uutybq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-value-binding-example.html

Answer (score 0):

You can access errors from a `FormControl` by using `getError` method.

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#getError

```
getErrorMessage(field: any) {
    let error = undefined;
    const formControl = this.field.control as FormControl;
        if (formControl.getError('required')){
            error = this.translate.instant('AUTH.field_required');
        }
    })
    return error
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But this was'nt the issue, event with just the `element.required`, I enter if the if. But for a reason I don't understand, the mat error doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Reactive forms? My issue was I was initializing the FormGroup and setting the id of that field to zero. I changed it to default to '' and validation started showing up.

i.e.

```
myForm = new FormGroup({
   'dropdown': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
});
```

Prior to that I was passing in a parameter and setting that parameter to zero, this way I could call a function to initialize my form for a new record or to edit an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

In **select-option** I think so better way is **onChange** and force error using:

```
setErrors({ required : true })
```

How alternative to **onChange** also you can do:

```
formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe((control) => ...
```

Good luck